# Pasting User Entered Information to another website. Ex: Tracking Number

Tags: php, html, web

I created an "tracking number" input box on my website...now I want that tracking number, once the user inputs it, pasted into some other website. How can I do that in PHP? Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you have to fake a form submission to that website, this could be easy or could be impossible.

Many tracking number forms allow you to put the tracking number into the query part of the URL.  try thst first.